# LPBYTE Macro Generates Error at Compile - C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, compiler-errors

I have the following code that is generating an error when I try to build the application:

```
#define LPAFDU LPBYTE;

typedef struct appAfDataIndIeee_tag
{
    integrPktHead_t head;
    BYTE flags;
    WORD dstShort;
    BYTE dstEndpoint;
    BYTE srcShort;
    BYTE srcIeee[8];
    WORD clusterId;
    BYTE afduLength;
    LPAFDU afdu;       // <-- error
} appAfDataIndIeee_t;
```

This is the error it generates:

> error C2208: 'BYTE *' : no members defined using this type
>   error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int

If I switch out `LPADFU` for `LPBYTE` it compiles successfully.  I would prefer to use a define or type-definition of `LPADFU`.  Does anyone know how I can make this work?  Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Get rid of the semicolon at the end of your `#define` (it's part of the macro):

```
#define LPAFDU LPBYTE
```

A far better way to do this, however, is to use `typedef` rather than `#define`:

```
typedef LPBYTE LPAFDU;
```

The most important advantage of typedefs is that they obey scope rules.

Comment: I agree, using a `typedef` is much better.

Comment: @Jim:  While you're at it, please get rid of the `typedef struct` nonsense.  It gets you nothing but complexity & confusion.

Comment: @John: `typedef struct` is pretty common, and it makes dynamic memory allocation a lot easier.  At any given time during my program's operation, it's next to impossible to know which structures will be needed.  Rather that wasting a bunch of memory having every possible struct statically defined, I prefer to dynamically allocate memory for each as it is needed.

Comment: @Jim:  It's not common in C++, although it might be in C.  And you don't need `typedef struct` to employ dynamic allocation in C++.

Comment: @Jim:  In C++, this is fine:  `class Gizmo {}; Gizmo* g = new Gizmo;`  No `typedef` required.

Comment: @John: Yes, I understand this, but a class object is overkill for what I'm trying to do: use structs to load and format a message to fire out over a serial interface.

Answer (score 2):

Remove the semicolon from your declaration of LPAFDU.

```
#define LPAFDU LPBYTE
```

You're probably thinking of a typedef statement, which would have a semicolon. With `#define`, the definition is inserted wherever the macro is, including your semicolon.